# Android -- How can we determine the Battery Usage statistics per application?

Tags: java, android, statistics, power-management

I am having trouble finding a class or API in Android documentation that would help me get battery usage statistics per application.

I have read `PowerManager` and `BatteryManager` classes but they are of no use.

However, I can find applications like PowerTutor that do provide battery usage statistics per application, so I think it's technically possible.

Can any one point me in right direction?

Comment: how u resolve your issue ?can u share link or any reference

Comment: Did you find how to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be surprised if such an API exists.  Rather, I expect that PowerTutor is using some sampling heuristics to estimate how much of the current battery usage to blame on each application.

Comment: I have a link to share , its about Android 1.6 Highlights http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-1.6-highlights.html . In that you will see , Battery Usage Indicator is built in Android too . Any chance PowerTutor is able to extract it somehow ?

Comment: Who knows.  Certainly, there doesn't seem to be a public API in the javadocs.